# Nested directives and parent scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

The problem I have can be see at http://jsfiddle.net/miketheanimal/2CcYp/13/ This strips down my problem to a minimum.

I have a controller "main", a directive "outer" which transclude's, and a directive "inner" which doesn't. Each directive has an isolate scope and a controller. The main and the directive controllers set $scope._name = '...' so I can tell them apart.

```
var module = angular.module('miketa', []);
function main ($scope) {
    $scope._name = 'main' ;
} ;
module.directive('outer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        controller: [ '$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope._name = 'outer' ;
            document.getElementById('opn').innerHTML = $scope.$parent._name ;
        }]}});
module.directive('inner', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<div></div>',
        controller: [ '$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope._name = 'inner' ;
            document.getElementById('ipn').innerHTML = $scope.$parent._name ;
        }]}});
```

The HTML nests these as main -> outer -> inner. The controller functions in the directives copy their **parent** scope name (ie., *$scope.$parent._name) into the rendered HTML (apologies for manipulating the DOM directly, it was the easiest way to display the names!).

I would expect *outer* to show the name from the controller (ie., "main") which is does, and I'd expect *inner* to show the name from *outer* (ie., "outer"), which is doesn't, rather it shows "main" as well.

The problem actually manifests itself since in the real code, I'd like to bind between the *inner* and *outer* scopes, but *inner* ends up binding to the *main* scope.

Comment: It's pretty logic i think your outer scope is isolate so how you can herit of it ?

Comment: Yes, the scopes are isolate, so they don't prototypically inherit, but they do have parent scopes (the $scope.$parent bit), and these don't seem to work the way I expect (inner -> outer -> main). As I note in the last paragraph, this becomes a problem when I try to bind between the scopes of *inner* and *outer* (ie., in the inner *scope: { innervar: '=outervar'}*).

Comment: Ah the ng-transclude set the ng-scope to false !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact it's not a bug, it's the desired behavior. From the [docs on the `$compile` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile):

> In a typical setup the widget creates an isolate scope, but the
>   transclusion is not a child, but a sibling of the isolate scope. This
>   makes it possible for the widget to have private state, and the
>   transclusion to be bound to the parent (pre-isolate) scope.

See also: [Why ng-transclude's scope is not a child of its directive's scope - if the directive has an isolated scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788289/why-ng-transcludes-scope-is-not-a-child-of-its-directives-scope-if-the-direc)

If you really need to get it work forget `ng-transclude` and do:

```js
var module = angular.module('miketa', []);

function main($scope) {
    $scope._name = 'main';
};
module.directive('outer', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<div><inner></inner></div>',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope._name = 'outer';
            document.getElementById('opn').innerHTML = $scope.$parent._name;
        }]
    }
});
module.directive('inner', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<div></div>',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope._name = 'inner';
            document.getElementById('ipn').innerHTML = $scope.$parent._name;
        }]
    }
});
```

And voila! It works.

Comment: I'd wondered if the transclude had something to do with it, I'd found some other sort-of-but-not-quite-related posts. But your change rather makes *outer* pointless, I might as well roll it into *inner*. What I'm trying to do is have a directive *outer* that can wrap different content (ie., wrap *inner1* and *inner2* and so on). Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: No any ng-trnasclude isolate the scope u have to accept that ! It's the logic of the transclusion in AngularJSn if you read the link thread and the docs

Comment: Lol good luck :) ! Directive API is the most powerful part of AngularJS but hard as hell ! Anyway maybe you have to accept or delete the question i don't know