# Angularjs directive change scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am still new to directive so unable to fully understand how it works, hoping some one will be able to help me pass a scope variable to the directive when user clicks an item on the ng-repeat.

the code looks like this

html

```
<tr ng-repeat='item in loadSummaries.items' ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}">
    <td>{{item.ShipmentId}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="showDetails(item)">details</button></td>
</tr>
```

the directive gets injected as below

```
<div id="searchRoot" class="embed-edit-item-form">
<div id="content-outer" class="row">
    <div id="form-holder">
        <div id="edit-form-content">
            <div id="edit-form-content-inner" style="background-color: transparent">
                <div ng-include src="'Client/Views/Shipper/shipment_details.html'">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear" style="clear: both">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
$scope.showDetails = function (item) {
    $scope.Message = "Details Clicked";
    $scope.$broadcast('event:show-edit-form', item);
}
```

and the directive.
**EDIT 2**

```
app.directive('embedEditItemForm', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    template: "<div></div>",
    transclude: true, //use transclusion
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller, linker) {
        linker(scope, function (clone) { //bind the content inside 
            elem.children().eq(0).append(clone); // add content to DOM

            var bidHolder = elem.find('#form-holder');
            var searchResult = elem.find('#searchResult');
            bidHolder.hide();
            scope.$on('event:show-edit-form', function (item) {
                scope.Shipment = item;
                searchResult.hide();
                bidHolder.slideDown('slow', function () {
                });
            });
            scope.$on('event:close-edit-form', function () {
                searchResult.show();
                bidHolder.slideUp();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

});

Issue I am having is how to pass the item from the ng-repeat in to the 'shipment_details.html' so that I can show more details there.  the code in the directive `scope.Shipment = item;` is not working.

**EDIT 1**
The complete Partial Page as below:

```
<div id="searchRoot" class="embed-edit-item-form">
<div id="content-outer" class="row">
    <div id="form-holder">
        <div id="edit-form-content">
            <div id="edit-form-content-inner" style="background-color: transparent">
                <div ng-include src="'Client/Views/Shipper/shipment_details.html'">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear" style="clear: both">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="searchResult">
    <div infinite-scroll='loadSummaries.nextPage()' infinite-scroll-disabled='loadSummaries.busy' infinite-scroll-distance='1'>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Shipment ID</th>
                    <th</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat='item in loadSummaries.items'>
                    <td>{{item.LoadId}}</td>
                    <td><button ng-click="showDetails(item)">details</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div ng-show='loadSummaries.busy'>Loading data...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the docs:

> In a typical setup the widget creates an isolate scope, but the
>   **transclusion is not a child, but a sibling of the isolate scope**. This
>   makes it possible for the widget to have private state, and the
>   transclusion to be bound to the parent (pre-isolate) scope.

Your content needs to inherit from your directive's scope to work. In this case, a simple solution is to avoid using isolate scope by removing `scope:{}`.

I'd like to point out why this is the expected behavior of angular. Transcluded content is arbitrary, so it **should not** have knowledge about your directive's implementation detail (what is available to use).

If you decide that the transcluded content **belongs** to the directive, it makes more sense to make it part of the directive's template (don't use transclusion).

For more information:

[Transclusion and scopes in angular: Why is this not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027254/transclusion-and-scopes-in-angular-why-is-this-not-working/23028300#23028300)

[Why ng-transclude's scope is not a child of its directive's scope - if the directive has an isolated scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788289/why-ng-transcludes-scope-is-not-a-child-of-its-directives-scope-if-the-direc)

[Confused about Angularjs transcluded and isolate scopes & bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653004/confused-about-angularjs-transcluded-and-isolate-scopes-bindings)

Comment: I don't have an issue with the broadcast. that's all working fine. Issue I have is that the `scope.$on('event:show-edit-form', function (item)` is receiving the correct item, but i don't know how to set it as a scope for the div on which the directive is applied. BTW I don't understand what you mean by the parent child relationship.

Comment: @Kiran: scopes in angular are inheriting, so there are child/parent relationships between scopes. I misunderstood your problem. Can you show me where you use your `embedEditItemForm` directive and how your `shipment_details.html` looks like? I guess there is an element `searchResult`, but I'm not sure

Comment: I have added the partial page where it fits. I think i get what you are saying, as I have the 2 div in the same level, the scopes are not properly setup due to `ng-repeat`. is it possible to define a separate controller instance for the directive to overcome this issue?

Comment: I did make the changes you suggested as you can see in the updated post, but now the issue is that `infinite-scroll='loadSummaries.nextPage()'` is not working. looks like its messing up  that scope. how can i retain that scope?

Comment: @Kiran: hmm, my bad. I did not see that your div with directive also wraps the `searchResults`. See updated answer.

Comment: @Kiran: I added more information to the answer to make it clearer. Hope it helps you more.