# AngularJS : Scope is not shared between nested transcluded directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

There are two directives `collection` and `element`, both of them transclude it's content, both of them have `scope: false` (default value).

This directives are used as wrapper on some container and wrapper on some items in that container, and used as follows:

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
 <collection>
    <element>inner1</element>
    <element>inner2</element>
    <element>inner3</element>
  </collection>
</body>
```

This directives are defined like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope){
    console.log('MyController', $scope.$id);
})
.directive('collection', function($compile){
    return {
        transclude: 'true',
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<header>header</header><div><ul ng-transclude></ul></div><footer>footer</footer>',
        link: function(scope){
            console.log('collection', scope.$id);
        }
    }
})
.directive('element', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<li><div ng-transclude></div></li>',
        link: function(scope){
            console.log('element', scope.$id);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that directive `element` is using not same scope as directive `collection`, and i can't figure out why.

**console output**

```html
MyController 003
element 004
element 004
element 004
collection 003
```

As you can see, `MyController` is sharing with `collection` same scope #3, but all  `element`-s use scope #4.

Here is working example: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fgcc3Q3qNGTDe9yHUikz?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log `scope.$id` to console in the linking function, you're logging the scope id of the directive itself. However, when you use transclusion in a directive, a new scope is also created for the transcluded content.

[image]

This is fairly simple to understand once you see it. Things become a bit more interesting once you [set isolate scope on a directive using transclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788289/why-ng-transcludes-scope-is-not-a-child-of-its-directives-scope-if-the-direc).